# PostgreSQL: Query that repeats last row result when current row is null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to created a query that repeats last row result when current row is null, e.g.:

Here is my data:

```
A1  |   B2
--------------
1   |   2
2   |   1
3   |   (null)
4   |   (null)
5   |   3
```

So I want that to be:

```
A1  |   B2
--------------
1   |   2
2   |   1
3   |   1
4   |   1
5   |   3
```

When the value is null, I want to fill with the last row result. I tried:

```
SELECT A1, COALESCE (B2, Last_Value (B2) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS B2 FROM

(SELECT 1 AS A1, 2 AS B2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3) TAB
```

But the result is:

```
A1  |   B2
--------------
1   |   2
2   |   1
3   |   1
4   |   (null)
5   |   3
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas, Postgres doesn't support the `ignore null` option for `lag()`.  But you can still do this.

The idea is to count the number of rows with a value in B2 prior to each row.  I'm assuming that A1 gives the ordering of the values.  Then you can use `max()` over this range to assign the value.

```
select t.a1,
       coalesce(t.b1, max(b2) over (partition by grp)) as b2
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when b2 is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by a1) as grp
      from tab t
     ) t;
```

I don't think the `coalesce()` is necessary, because the `max()` should be calculating the right value even when `b2` is not null.  But, I think it makes the code clearer.

EDIT:

The above query can be slightly simplified to:

```
select t.a1,
       coalesce(t.b1, max(b2) over (partition by grp)) as b2
from (select t.*,
             count(b2) over (order by a1) as grp
      from tab t
     ) t;
```

Comment: This answer saved me! Thank you!